# Entity expected object returned symfony

Tags: symfony, object, doctrine, relation, many-to-one

I'm trying to get an item from the database and pass it to a new item to push to the database.

```
$post = $entityManager->getRepository('App:Post')
            ->find($id);

$comment->setPost($post)
```

the `setPost` looks like the following:

```
public function setPost(Post $post): self
    {
        $this->post = $post;

        return $this;
    }
```

and the `$post` variable:

```
 /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Post", inversedBy="comments")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     */
    private $post;
```

But when i try to set the post like `setPost($post)` it gives me the following error:

> Expected parameter of type '\App\Entity\Post', 'object' provided

Comment: `'App:Post'` somehow looks wrong, have you tried `Post::class` (with the appropriate `use` clause)?

Comment: Same problem, i tried `App:Post` because i found it online. When I dump ` $post` the output is correct. I get all the correct data from it.

Comment: App:Post and Post::class are identical as far as retrieving a repository goes.  Doctrine has it's only little namespace system that deals with App:Post.  Post::class is probably a better choice as your IDE will help a bit more.  As far as the question goes, since you confirmed $post is the expected class then maybe some other code is being executed?  Maybe  temporarily remove the typehint from setPost and see what happens.

Comment: @Cerad it works when I remove the `Post` from `SetPost` so now it is `SetPost($post)`. But I don't know _why_ it works and if it is good practice.

Comment: It is not good practice.  Is your Post entity and Comment entity in the same namespace i.e. App\Entity\Comment?  I guess you might also try the magical clearing of the cache.  php version? Try to go to 7.4.4 if possible.

Comment: They are in the same namespace `App\Entity` I cleared the cache.php with `service apache2 reload`. And put `Post $post` back into the function. It _does_ work on the page and inserts it in the database. But in the code it gives the error again.

Comment: Maybe take a step back and verify what you are seeing.  If it is generating an error message then it is not going to work unless the error message is coming from some place else.  You should not be using apache during development.  Use the [Symfony development server](https://symfony.com/doc/current/setup/symfony_server.html#getting-started).  Maybe things will settle down.

Comment: what do you mean when you say "in the code it gives the error"? do you mean in your IDE (eclipse/phpstorm/vs code)? this is usually due to return values that aren't quite explicit in symfony/doctrine and the code analysis tool used in IDEs warning about the difference. usually you can fix this by adding a "magic" comment to tell the code analysis what your var is, specifically the first code line you posted here `$post = $entityManager...` - the line is dynamic and the interfaces defined return an `object` on `find()`. add the line before: `/** @var Post $post */` (may be null though)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume, that the error you see is from your integrated developent environment (IDE), for example eclipse, vs code, phpstorm, and others. But the code - when actually executed - should work.

Now, the error most likely stems from a static code analysis running in the background of said IDE, which will look at the statement and trying to analyze according to the called methods, accessed properties etc. of which type your variables are.

So, let's do this slowly (and you can probably hover over the `$vars` and `->methods()` do verify. The line I'm interested in is

```
$post = $entityManager->getRepository('App:Post')
            ->find($id);
```

so `$entityManager` is of type `EntityManagerInterface`, which has a `getRepository` method with one required parameter of type `string` (`'App:Post'` in your case), and it will return an object of type `ObjectRepository`, which has a method `find` which requires one parameter (`mixed`, don't ask), and returns `?object` which means, an `object` or `null`. So, `$post` is of type `object` (best case, or null, in which case it would fail!). Now, the next line obviously expects a parameter of type `Post` and not of type `object`, thus the warning/notice/error.

Now, static code analysis is quite helpful up to a certain level, but it isn't infallible because it has limitations. It doesn't know what runtime will *actually* return, it just assumes that the type hints found in the code (of doctrine) are sufficiently specific - which they aren't in your case.

#### the easy fix

add a doc string to tell static code analysis what the variable `$post`'s type actually is:

```
/** @var Post $post */
$post = $entityManager->getRepository('App:Post')
            ->find($id);
```

this explicitly tells the static analysis tool, that `$post` is of type `Post`, maybe you have to write `App\Entity\Post` or even `\App\Entity\Post`.

#### the hard fix

Alternatively, you could implement your own `PostRepository` (doctrine provides *some* help) and define a function like `function findById($id) :Post` - which would explicitly tell static code analysis, what the return type is when you call it in your code (injected in your function via dependency injection: `PostRepostory $postRepository`):

```
$post = $postRepository->findById($id);
```

If you're using lots and lots of different entities, this is a very verbose solution but depending on your project it might be worth it, since you explicitly name the dependencies instead of injecting the very unspecific (as we have seen) `EntityManagerInterface`. Using the EntityManagerInterface might make testing HELL (imho!).

Comment: Thank you for the good explanation! I understand the issue now and how to solve it.